# Scaling Background things to content height

Tags: css, height, scaling

So i want to make a back ground box that scales to the height of the content pf the page using CSS. I've tried all I know how to do. The back ground box is broken into three parts top middle and bottom. This is so as to not distort the shadow around the box when i scale it. Anything that controls height will have to apply to the middle section. Heres the website http://www.unitedbygaming.com/test.php and you can right click page source to see anything you need. Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all your background image is not in center so here is the code to make it center

```
body {
background-image: url("/images/site_background.png");
background-position: center top;
```

}

remove from body css.

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Secondly:

Instead of using this image `<img src="/images/dfbox/mid.png" id="dfboxmid">` in html try to call it as background image and slice the image its height (2435px) it too much thats the reason you page height is increasing.

you can call the background image and repeat it in repeat-y direction.

You can see the below image in which i removed your shadowed image.

[image]

Instead of using all three images in one div use it separately in three separate div's like Header, middle and footer this will be more convenient.

Comment: still is there any issues please let us know.